# jQuery trigger('click') not firing .click event on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, triggers, click

I have table with a check-all checkbox in the header which checks all the checkboxes in that column of the table:

```
<input class="check-all" type="checkbox" id="masterCheck" />
```

However, on one of my pages I would like to automatically check the check-all checkbox on page load.

To do this I've attempted to fire a trigger('click') function like the one below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#masterCheck").attr('checked')) {
    } else {
        $("#masterCheck").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

This checks the checkbox fine, but doesn't fire my custom click event for checkboxes with the class **.check-all** (below):

```
$(function () {
    $('.check-all').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('table:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

I've also tried adding a Javascript setTimeout, thinking that the custom click function wasn't being loaded quite yet, but it still didn't fire the custom click function after waiting 1, 2, and 3 seconds.

Upon page load, I can then un-check my pre-checked checkbox and re-check it to check all of the checkboxes in the column perfectly.

Do I have to add something special to my jQuery on the Document.ready to allow it to fire the custom click event?

***EDIT1:

Ok, I've attempted to add the custom click event right above the document.ready function on my page to ensure it's loaded (as the previous custom click event  is in a master .js file used in my _Layout). In addition to this, I've changed the class of my checkbox to correspond with my new custom click event so I don't conflict with the one in my master .js file.

```
<input class="check-allx" type="checkbox" id="masterCheck" />


// Check all checkboxes when the one in a table head is checked:
    $(function () { 
        $('.check-allx').click(function () {
            $(this).parents('table:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
            alert(this);
        });
    });
// Check for unchecked masterCheck
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#masterCheck").attr('checked')) {
        } else {
            //$("#masterCheck").trigger('click');
            $("#masterCheck").click();
        }
    });
```

This seems to throw my alert within the custom click event which is progress, but to no avail do all my checkboxes check like they should. Note: I've also changed the trigger('click') to a .click(), which both do the same thing in my situation.

Comment: Just as a further test for your possible theory that the custom event handler may not be defined yet, have you tried defining your custom click handler directly above your check, just to make a minimal version of that problem?

Comment: Ben: I've tried this in EDIT1 above. It is now breaking into my custom click event, but all my checkboxes still aren't clicking as they should.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Update: This only applies to jQuery 1.8 and below. This was [fixed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#checkbox-radio-state-in-a-trigger-ed-quot-click-quot-event).*

The problem is that manually calling `click()` in jQuery works differently than an actual click.

When you actually click, first the checkbox state is changed, then your click handler is called.

When you call `click()`, first the click handler is called, then the checkbox state is changed.

So when you call `click`, in your click handler, `this.checked` is still going to be false. You can fix this by making it a `change` handler instead of a `click` handler, like this:

```
$('.check-allx').change(function () {
    $(this).parents('table:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

See [In jQuery, why does programmatically triggering 'click()' on a checkbox not immediately check it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678103/in-jquery-why-does-programmatically-triggering-click-on-a-checkbox-not-immed/7678735#7678735) for a fuller explanation of the difference between actual manual clicks and jquery triggered clicks.

Comment: great answer, explains the situation perfectly and gives a viable solution.

Comment: great answer.  My solution was to also import a newer version of jquery and to click() with it.  This was in confluence, so I had no choice but to keep the old one.  See here how to use 2 version of jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1566595/265877

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
$("#recurrence").trigger('click');
```

The below will be executed after the checkbox state change.

```
$("#recurrence").click(function () {
    $(this).change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".recurr-section").show();
        } else {
            $(".recurr-section").hide();
        }
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the checked attribute programmatically doesn't trigger a corresponding click event, so you'd have to add your own `.trigger('click')` when you set the attribute.

Comment: That is when you set the `checked` attribute via code. But clicking through code should work - check http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/sBJ8L/

Answer (score 0):

Alright, considering I only needed that functionality on that individual page I've gone the easy way out and avoided trying to launch the custom click event all together.

After a coffee this morning it a was a bit clearer to me. I've added this code as a work-around.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('table#OHTable input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
```

This simply checks ALL my checkboxes in my Table, and the proper click event is still fired when my masterCheck is clicked after the fact.